# Cutting a DataFrame with pandas.iloc doesn't change its copied variable? (Copied with "=" not pd.copy())

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame `df` :

```py
s = pd.Series([3, 4, 5], ['earth', 'mars', 'jupiter'])
k = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], ['earth', 'mars', 'jupiter'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'mass': s, 'diameter': k})
```

```py
         mass  diameter
earth       3         1
mars        4         2
jupiter     5         3
```

I copy `df` to a new variable `df2` using:

```
df2 = df
```

The following change will apply to both `df`and `df2`. This is understandable.

```
df["mass"]["earth"] = 100
```

But this next change will only apply one DataFrame:

```
df = df.iloc[:2,:]
```

Can someone explain this behavior? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `df2 = df` does not make a copy, you would need `df2 = df.copy()`. Similarly, `df = df.iloc[:2,:]` does not modify `df` in place, but assigns the `df` name to a new dataframe `df.iloc[:2,:]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
df2 = df
```

both df2 and df point to the same object.

If you were to modify one in place (`df.loc["earth", "mass"] = 100`), the "other one" (actually same) would be modified.

However when you do:

```
df = df.iloc[:2,:]
```

`df2` still points to the original dataframe, **while `df` now points to a new object** (the `df.iloc[:2,:]` slice).

demo:

```
df2 = df
id(df) == id(df2)
# True               # same object

df = df.iloc[:2,:]
id(df) == id(df2)
# False              # no longer the same object

id(df.iloc[:2,:]) == id(df.iloc[:2,:])
# False              # each call creates a new copy
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df2 = df.copy()
```

use this make a separate copy, otherwise they both point to the same data in memory